# Is there any possible to install bash in distroless image?

Tags: docker, fluent-bit

I'm working on Fluent-bit I need to execute entry-point script in the container but fluent-bit image is distroless base image so any possibilities are there to install bash or any idea for executing that script?

please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `COPY` a shell-binary and the entrypoint to your image like

```
FROM fluent/fluent-bit:1.4
COPY bash /bin/bash
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

This would be analog to: [Install Bash on scratch Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001121/install-bash-on-scratch-docker-image)

As an alternative you can use a normal distro-image and install `fluent-bit` via the distro's package manager or compile.

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/linux

Comment: is that possible to use a ubuntu image and install fluentbit?

Comment: Yes. Pick your distro and follow the install instructinns from fluent-bit in link above.